# Mvc Model Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I keep getting this error:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'OutsourcedTicketPlatform.UI.ViewModels.Home.AccountSearchViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'OutsourcedTicketPlatform.UI.ViewModels.Home.AccountDetailsViewModel'.

Home controller:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult SearchResults(AccountSearchViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AccountDetailsViewModel accountDetails = new AccountDetailsViewModel(model.CustomerReferenceNumber);
            return View(accountDetails);
        }

        return View("Index");
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult MobileResults(AccountDetailsViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AccountDetailsViewModel accountDetails = new AccountDetailsViewModel(model.CustomerReferenceNumber);
            return View(accountDetails);
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

MobileIssueReporterview:

```
  @model OutsourcedTicketPlatform.UI.ViewModels.Home.AccountDetailsViewModel



     @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Mobile Issue Reporter";
       }

       <h2>Mobile Issue Reporter</h2>

       <p>Hi (CustomerName) are you phoning today to log the mobile device as lost or                 stolen?</p>


          <p>"Please Confirm your mobile number"</p>

           <p>@Html.TextBox("mobileNumber")</p>
```

Search results view (this navigates to the mobile issue reporter)

```
   @model OutsourcedTicketPlatform.UI.ViewModels.Home.AccountDetailsViewModel

   @{
          ViewBag.Title = "Key Account Management";
     }

      <fieldset>
       <legend>@ViewBag.Title</legend>

       <p>Please provide the account name:</p>
        @foreach (var item in Model.AccountContacts)
      {
          @Html.RadioButton("AccountContact", item) @item
    }
    <input id="ContactNotListedButton" type="button" value="Contact name not on list" />

        <p>Please provide the first line of the billing address:</p>
         @Html.RadioButton("BillingAddressFirstLine", Model.BillingAddressFirstLine,  false) @Model.BillingAddressFirstLine

  <input id="NoMatchingDetailsButton" type="button" value="No Matching Details" />

  @* 1 = Unicom, 2 = Titan *@
  @if (Model.AccountType == 1 || Model.AccountType == 2)
   {
      <input id="NextButton" type="button" value="Next" />
   }

    @if (Model.AccountType == 1 && Model.IsKeyAccount &&   Model.HasActiveMobileContracts)
   {
      using (Html.BeginForm("MobileResults", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
      {            
        @Html.Hidden("CustomerReferenceNumber","123456")
        @Html.Hidden("customerName", "John Smith")
        @Html.Hidden("mobileNumber", "123456789")
        <input type="submit" value="Mobile Lost or Stolen?" />
       }
   }
   </fieldset>
```

The error is happening when I click on the Mobile Lost or Stolen? button

Comment: Does the error happen when you click `Mobile Lost or Stolen?` button?

Comment: Yes ekad, that is correct

Comment: Can you add the code of the other `MobileResults` action method that has `[HttpPost]` attribute?

Comment: I have added this but still having the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Seems You are passing populated values with the model **AccountSearchViewModel**  but  that     view is expecting data from **AccountDetailsViewModel** chek with AccountDetailsViewModel model it will work fine.